# Min, Max and equals for three numbers in Java

Tags: java

I am currently up with Java and there is a question which I am not getting a correct approach to. It says to find out the minimum and maximum of two numbers, as well as the numbers which are equal, in  if statements (nested ifs are allowed) and It's getting very complex and hard-to-understand. Can you suggest a better way to do it ? 
Here's my code :

```
long num1 = 1 ;
long num2 = 1 ;
long num3 = 1 ;
boolean error = false ;
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in) ;
do {
   if(error)
   {
      System.out.println("Sorry, error. Try again") ;
   }
   error = false ;
   System.out.print("Enter the first number : ") ;
   num1 = sc.nextLong() ;
                
   System.out.print("Enter the second number : ") ;
   num2 = sc.nextLong() ;
                
   System.out.print("Enter the third number : ") ;
   num3 = sc.nextLong() ;
                
   if(num1<=0 || num2<=0) error = true ;
   // number entered will iterate if error...
while(error == true) ;
```

```
// main conditions
if(num1>num2)
{
    if(num1>num3)
    {
        System.out.println(num1 + " is the greatest number") ;
        if(num2<num3) 
        {
            System.out.println(num2 + " is the smallest") ;
        } else if(num2==num3) {
            System.out.println(num2 + " and " + num3 + " are equal") ;
        }
     } 
 } else if(num2>num3) {
     if(num1!=num2)
     {
        System.out.println(num2 + " is the greatest number") ;
     } else {
        System.out.println(num2 + " and " + num1 + " are equal") ;
     }
     if(num1<num3) 
     {
        System.out.println(num1 + " is the smallest number") ;
     } else if(num1==num3) {
        System.out.println(num1 + " and " + num3 + " are equal") ;
     }
     } else if(num3>num2){
        if(num3!=num1)
        {
             System.out.println(num3 + " is the greatest") ;
        } else {
             System.out.println(num3 + " and " + num1 + " are equal") ;
        }
     }
}
```

I know this program does not cover all the possibilities, and sure enough, when i run it, it does not display all the correct results. Can anybody send me an organised program (with comments) please? It will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You could do `long min = Math.min(Math.min(num1, num2), num3);` The same class will help for max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to this question is really easy (can't see why nobody saw it before) - just use the AND operator.
So for finding out the GREATEST number among the three :

```
if(num1>num2 && num1>num3)
{
     System.out.println(num1 + " is the greatest") ;
} else if(num2>num3 && num2>num1) {
     System.out.println(num2 + " is the greatest") ;
} else if(num3>num2 && num3>num1) {
     System.out.println(num3 + " is the greatest") ;
}
```

For finding out the SMALLEST number :

```
if(num1<num2 && num1<num3) {
     System.out.println(num1 + " is the smallest") ;
} else if(num2<num3 && num2<num1) {
     System.out.println(num2 + " is the smallest") ;
} else if(num3<num2 && num3<num1) {
     System.out.println(num3 + " is the smallest") ;
}
```

for finding out the EQUAL numbers :

```
if(num1==num2 && num2==num3) {
    System.out.println("All the numbers are equal") ;
} else if(num2==num3) {
    System.out.println(num2 + " is equal to " + num3) ;
} else if(num1==num3) {
    System.out.println(num1 + " is equal to " + num3) ;
} else if(num1==num2) {
    System.out.println(num1 + " is equal to " + num2) ;
}
```

Combining all of them :

```
public static void main()
    {
            long num1 = 1 ;
            long num2 = 1 ;
            long num3 = 1 ;
            boolean error = false ;
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in) ;
            do {
                if(error)
                {
                    System.out.println("Sorry, error. Try again") ;
                }
                error = false ;
                System.out.print("Enter the first number : ") ;
                num1 = sc.nextLong() ;
                
                System.out.print("Enter the second number : ") ;
                num2 = sc.nextLong() ;
                
                System.out.print("Enter the third number : ") ;
                num3 = sc.nextLong() ;
                
                if(num1<=0 || num2<=0) error = true ;
                // number entered will iterate if error...
            } while(error == true) ;
            if(num1>num2 && num1>num3)
            {
                System.out.println(num1 + " is the greatest") ;
            } else if(num2>num3 && num2>num1)
            {
                System.out.println(num2 + " is the greatest") ;
            } else if(num3>num2 && num3>num1)
            {
                System.out.println(num3 + " is the greatest") ;
            }
            
            if(num1<num2 && num1<num3)
            {
                System.out.println(num1 + " is the smallest") ;
            } else if(num2<num3 && num2<num1)
            {
                System.out.println(num2 + " is the smallest") ;
            } else if(num3<num2 && num3<num1)
            {
                System.out.println(num3 + " is the smallest") ;
            }
            
            System.out.println() ;    // for clarity
            if(num1==num2 && num2==num3)
            {
                System.out.println("All the numbers are equal") ;
            } else if(num2==num3)
            {
                System.out.println(num2 + " is equal to " + num3) ;
            } else if(num1==num3)
            {
                System.out.println(num1 + " is equal to " + num3) ;
            } else if(num1==num2)
            {
                System.out.println(num1 + " is equal to " + num2) ;
            }
            
    }
}
```

**[NOTE:**  *the lines are not indented properly-so please overlook that.***]**

Comment: Swap `if(num1==num2 && num2==num3)` with `if(num1==num2)` (with their blocks of course). Otherwise the execution will never enter the `"All the numbers are equal"` block.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple, you can use the max and min functions of the Math module. It goes like this

```
long a, b, c
a = Math.max(num1, Math.max(num2, num3))
//a will be the maximum number
b = Math.min(num1,Math.min(num2, num3))
//b will be the minimum number

//c is the middle number
if(num1 < a & num1 > b)
    c = num1
else if(num2 < a & num2 > b)
    c = num2
else
    c = num3
```

Comment: I know I can use this...But can show how to do it using nested ifs ?? It'll be very complex that's why I wrote this question.